# Azure yaml build and release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

So I am deploying a web application on the Azure app service with azure YAML pipelines.

The way I am doing this is that I have created 2 YAML pipelines, one for build and the other for release where I have multi-stage for different environments. for ex; Dev, Test, and Prod.

The reason I have divided it into two pipelines is that my build pipeline produces build artifacts and by using the Resouces section on my release pipeline I can select the previously generated build(from the UI) and deploy it to whatever stage I want to. The idea is that I don't want to build every single time when I need deployment to one of those stages. I should be able to use the previously produced artifacts as well as the old build artifact version. Below is my release pipeline and how I am using the Resources section.

Release Pipeline

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: myappbuild  
    source: build-test # name of the pipeline that produces an artifact
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages: 
- stage: 'DeployToDev'
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy 
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: dev 
    pool: 
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    strategy: 
      runOnce: 
        deploy:
          steps:          
          - download: myappbuild
            artifact: drop  
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
            inputs:
              packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
              AppSettings: '-ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $(EnvironmentName) -ReleaseName $(Release.ReleaseName) -BuildId $(Build.BuildId)'
```

This is running fine. I am able to pick the previous build from the UI and can deploy that build to whatever stage I have in my release pipeline.

**Questions:**

1. In the release pipeline it's difficult to say what is currently deployed on what stages. I want to be able to tell what is in each environment based on what's been run. so In my case, I have 3 env and I want to be able to tell which run was for which env. since the Classic UI pipeline has a concept of release where it shows which artifact is currently deployed where in just 1 screen. wherein YAML you only get to see 3 green dots for each environment I have under the Runs section which doesn't tell what is currently deployed on the Dev stage.
2. Can I achieve this within one pipeline, rather than creating 2 pipelines? Can I have just 1 pipeline having my build and release? I know it's possible to have a multi-stage where I can have one stage for build and others for my release. but then how am I able to pick the previous build to deploy to whatever stage. since I am not sure if I can use the resources section in this use case. Idea is that I don't want to run build all the time. if this is something achievable can someone please direct me to correct the document?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd combine the build and deploy stages together, something like this:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:
    - task: YourBuildTask1
      inputs:
        YourInputsHere: ...
    - task: Etc
      inputs:
        Etc: ...
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: ...
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
- stage: DEV
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
    - deployment: Deployment
      variables:
        - template: myDevVariables.template.yml
      environment: DEV
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:     
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
              inputs:
                packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'
                AppSettings: '-ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $(EnvironmentName) -ReleaseName $(Release.ReleaseName) -BuildId $(Build.BuildId)'
- stage: Test
  dependsOn: DEV
  jobs:
    - deployment: Deployment
      variables:
        - template: myTestVariables.template.yml
      environment: Test
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:     
            - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
              displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
              inputs:
                packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'
                AppSettings: '-ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT $(EnvironmentName) -ReleaseName $(Release.ReleaseName) -BuildId $(Build.BuildId)'
```

Obviously not debugged, but I'm doing something similar here in my own pipelines successfully. You make the first deployment stage dependent on the build, each subsequent environment dependent on the previous. You add approval gates for each environment to add manual intervention and prevent the build from just deploying everywhere at once.

Note, in this example, I've substituted `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` for `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`, as I've found frequently with YAML pipelines that `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` has a different value for different job types.

In the example below, if I didn't like the result of the 20200105.1 deployment, I could click on the 20201218.1 run below it, and choose a new environment to deploy to.

[image: Example Run List]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. but would this allow me to pick the artifact produced; let's say 3 days ago(which is not the latest one). The idea is to pick the old build version and apply that version to deployment stages(with the use-case you have provided). @WaitingForGuacamole Thank you :)

Comment: Actually, it should - when you run the pipeline, it will create a "Run" under the Pipeline, and you can see all of the environments to which that build has been promoted. If you want to deploy an older build, you just go down to the "Run" that corresponds to the build you want to deploy, and choose the environment to (re-)deploy to. I've included a sample above.

Comment: unfortunately, I don't find a way to pick the old build and deploy that build against the environment stages. even if it's possible, I have to run that build again, which I don't want to as my build stage takes a lot of time to execute. instead, I can pick the old(deployed) build and deploy it to environment stages without running the build stage. and this is why I had divided the pipelines into 2 part where it allows me to pick an old build and without running it again I can deploy that build to stages and that way I could save deployment time. @WaitingForGuacamole

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you have to run the build again - each "Run" (list above is an example) should retain the build artifact, so long as your build stage published the artifact. At that point you can go to any "Run" and choose an environment to which to deploy that build artifact.

Comment: consider this scenario, where I am running the build stage, producing build artifacts. I want to deploy it to the Dev stage at that moment. and later let's say 2 weeks after I want deployment with the integration or prod stages with that artifact without running build. how would I achieve that?

Comment: OK. You run the build stage. You deploy it to DEV. Great. You have a run list with the build/deploy entry that shows that happened. You go on and do a bunch of other builds. Those also create entries in the run list. Also great. Two weeks later, you decide you want the old artifact you built to deploy to integration or prod. Click on the run list entry for that old build and you should have the option to deploy it to those environments (provided you have privileges based on approval gates). This assumes you used the Publish build artifacts step in your build (see previous comment).

Comment: Thank you @WaitingForGuacamole. I see using the approval gate we can pause the deployment to the Integration test. and whenever that approval happens, the integration stage will run. But when it's in that pause mode, is that pipeline still considers to be running? and taking up one of the build queues? or does it mean the pipeline totally stops or is it just sitting in a queue waiting for confirmation approval? if we never approve the confirmation would it assume declined pipeline? again thank you so much for doing this :)

Comment: The pipeline really doesn't care about "running". It processes a job, and lands in a workflow state. Based on that state and other rules, you can do lots of different things (like redeploying an old release after a new release deployed).

Answer (score 0):

I would combine them as that is where the value really is.  Keeping them separate just leads to move overhead and maintenance.  If worried about a CI/CD YAML can support that via a single pipeline with a condition wrapped around the deployments stages to check the branch using `- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')}} :`

For question on environment visibility click the "Environment" button in Azure DevOps as it will show all the jobs that have hit that environment across all the repos within the project.

Best practice would be to create a CD for each commit into master.  This would create a release for all environments and deploy to DEV.  Thus keeping a release for every build.

Comment: The problem with having everything in one pipeline is that I have to run a build every single time when I want to deploy that build to release stages which I don't want to. as my build takes lots of time, so idea is that you can take whatever previously produced build(either latest or old build) and deploy it to stages without running it, it would reduce the deployment time. with CICD in one pipeline, I can't skip the build stage running. @DreadedFrost

Comment: Again, so long as your build stage has a step to publish the artifact, any run should allow you to do what you're looking to do (deploy something previously built without rebuilding it).

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole Hi, I'm also a bit new in the YAML pipelines but it feels like sticking Build and Release definitions all in one place seems to me like breaking the Single Responsibility Principle. It sounds a bit risky to me and e.g. IN A VERY THEORY if you create a wrong YAML definition, the broken code can be released to some env later. Please correct me if I'm wrong here. The other thing is IMO in the perfect world it would be cool to be able to run/test the Build YAML pipeline in localhost before creating a PR(which is not supported at the mo).

Comment: Anyway, why having everything in one pipeline is better than having a separate Build pipeline and Release one? I'm super confused about this here...

Comment: Everything in one pipeline streamlines the process from a DevOps perspective.  There no longer is a separate location with separate Maintenace for a build + release. This also is in comparison with the classic build/releases and converts this process to code to allow for SCM.  With the point about YAML deploying broken code to an environment. This shouldn't happen as ideally the deploy will use the same artifact (minus configs) for each environment.  Additionally, this is mitigated further by using templates where the steps are defined once and reused.

Comment: @DreadedFrost beat me to it on a holiday weekend, thanks. I hear where you're going with SRP and pipelines, but to be honest, even though the  YAML pipeline is "code", I see the build and deploy activities as linked. Yes, it's possible to deploy broken code, but to me that's a matter of broken process (someone didn't validate the build and DEV deployment before promoting), and that happens no matter what.